# Retrieving a user from a PeopleEditor and setting it into a list item by code

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm with SharePoint 2007 and want the person who enter in the text box[UserName to be added to the list of Employees;

**A have a form, where "Create a new employee"**

[image]

**This is my list and type of "UserName is : Person Or Groud" ;**

[image]

**My Code is :**

```
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPList empList = web.Lists["Employees"];

                SPListItem itemAdd = empList.Items.Add();

                itemAdd["Title"] = Convert.ToString(txtFullname.Text);
```

**What should I write here to add a UserName[peoplePicker]? in LIST**

```
                itemAdd["EGN"] = Convert.ToString(txtEGN.Text);
                itemAdd["DateOfReceipt"] = dtc.SelectedDate;
                itemAdd.Update();

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;                
            }
```

[EDIT] here's the screenshot of the errors I get when using the 2010 version of the code provided by @Evariste:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
itemAdd["UserName"] = GetSelectedUserInPeoplePicker(web, myPeopleEditor);
```

where `GetSelectedUserInPeoplePicker` is as follow [edited to accomodate SP **2007** -I has missed the SharePoint version mentionned in the question]:

**SharePoint 2007 version:**

```
    public static SPUser GetSelectedUserInPeoplePicker(SPWeb web, PeopleEditor PE)
    {
        SPUser res = null;
        if(PE.ResolvedEntities.Count == 0)
            return res;

        PickerEntity entity = (PickerEntity)PE.ResolvedEntities[O];
        string entityType = entity.EntityData["PrincipalType"].ToString().ToLower();

        switch (entityType)
        {
            case "user":
                res = web.EnsureUser(entity.Key);
                break;
            case "securitygroup":
                break;
            case "sharepointgroup":
                break;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

**SharePoint 2010/2013 version:**

```
public static SPUser GetSelectedUserInPeoplePicker(SPWeb web, PeopleEditor PE)
{
    SPUser res = null;
    if(PE.ResolvedEntities.Count == 0)
        return res;

    PickerEntity entity = (PickerEntity)PE.ResolvedEntities[O];
    if (entity.Claim == null) // Classic mode
    {
        entityType = entity.EntityData["PrincipalType"].ToString().ToLower();
    }
    else
    {
        if (entity.EntityType.ToLower() == "user")
           entityType = "user";
        else if (entity.EntityType.ToLower() == "secgroup")
           entityType = "securitygroup";
    }

    switch (entityType)
    {
        case "user":
            res = web.EnsureUser(entity.Key);
            break;
        case "securitygroup":
            break;
        case "sharepointgroup":
            break;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: "Not work" meaning?... I'm using that code for ages with no problem. What happens with it on your side? Please, give more details.

Comment: I apologize for what my mistake was. I have attached below a picture of the problem. I would be grateful if you help me.

Comment: OK, I see... SP2007. My code was for 2010/2013. Edited my answer to adapt for 2007.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] UsersSeperated = peopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts.Split(',');

    SPFieldUserValueCollection UserCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

    foreach (string UserSeperated in UsersSeperated)
    {
        web.EnsureUser(UserSeperated);
        SPUser User = web.SiteUsers[UserSeperated];
        SPFieldUserValue UserName = new SPFieldUserValue(web, User.ID, User.LoginName);
        UserCollection.Add(UserName);
     }

    itemAdd["UserName"] = UserCollection;
```

This is working for SP 2007!